# OnQuickLaunch ignored in list instance

Tags: 2010, site-definition

I have a list instance in which I set the `OnQuickLaunch` to `TRUE` and refer to in my Site Definition.
However it gets ignored, why could it be?

```
<ListInstance Title="Assistance"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    FeatureId="b0de3983-59af-4453-9e19-abda6b6b0c25"
    RootWebOnly="FALSE"
    TemplateType="10511"
    Url="/Assistance"
    Description="As-built List Instance"/>
```

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54135/declarative-onquicklaunch-property-not-working-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: @MuhammadRaja Didn't work. Also seems to be a SP2013 solution only :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your Site Definition you can add NavBarLink in quicklaunch's NavBar in NavBars element in ONET.XML

Example:

```
<NavBars>
    ....
    ....
  <NavBar Name="Lists"  .....  ID="1003">
    <NavBarLink Name="List_1" Url="/Site1_Name/Lists/List1_Name/AllItems.aspx"/>
  </NavBar>
....
</NavBars>
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454677%28office.14%29.aspx)

and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462632.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add   `QuickLaunchUrl = "Text"` to your list instance, e.g.

```
<ListInstance Title="Assistance"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    FeatureId="b0de3983-59af-4453-9e19-abda6b6b0c25"
    RootWebOnly="FALSE"
    TemplateType="10511"
    Url="Lists/Assistance"
    QuickLaunchUrl = "Lists/Assistance/AllItems.aspx"
    Description="As-built List Instance"/>
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, no difference :/